# Instant preview and Vi commands for LaTeX on a Mac?

Tags: editors, mactex

I have Sublime Text 2 and Skim installed along with MacTeX and [LaTeXTools](https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools) on my Macbook. I think this setting is really great, especially because Sublime Text 2 supports Vi commands via the 'Vintage mode'. But in addition to that, I would really like **'instant preview features'** like the gummi LaTeX editor. (An example image of 'instant preview features' [here](http://www.charlietanksley.net/philtex/vim-live-latex-preview/).)

I'm willing to give up my current LaTeX working enviroment, if I can have instant previews, that work with a text editor that supports Vi commands on my Mac. (My Mac OS is Mountain Lion.)

Does anybody know any tools, apps, or libaries that support such features?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: @Aradnix I didn't. Still a live issue :)

Comment: Uhm... if I understand well, what you want is to use another software for visualize the result or the advance every time you compile your file. If that's right, I would say that evince works fine, but unfortunately it has not support for mac. I use sublime text on windows, linux and mac, but mac is the OS I use less, so I don't know which option really could recommend you, would have to investigate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Latexian for Mac OS X](http://tacosw.com/latexian/) is a nice option for those who want instant preview. (Vintage mode not supported.)

Comment: Does it really support a VI (or vintage) mode? How far?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Latexian does not support vintage mode.